# I want to refresh a page,whenever I click the tab in the tab panel

Tags: visualforce, javascript, tabpanel

I have 3 tabs,whenever I click the tab,pageblock has to be refreshed.need your help,thanks in advance.

```
<apex:page id="pg" standardController="Noise_Dictionary__c" extensions="SynonymsDictionary_cls" tabstyle="Noise_Dictionary__c" >
   <script>
   function myFunction(){
   var query="select id,name from Noise_Dictionary__c"; 
    var records = sforce.connection.query(query); 
    var records1 = records.getArray('records');
   alert(records);

   }
   </script>
    <script  type='text/javascript'>
        var waitTime = 1;
        var countDown = waitTime + 1;
        var started = false;

        function resetTimer() {
            countDown = waitTime + 1;
            if (started == false) {
                started = true;
                runCountDown();
            }
        }

        function runCountDown() { 
            countDown--;
            if (countDown <= 0) {
                fetchResults();
                started = false;
            } else {
                window.setTimeout(runCountDown, 1000);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .activeTab {
            font-size:1.25em;
            font-style:normal;
            font-family: 'Calibri';
            font-weight:bold;
            background-color: #3090C7; 
            color:white;
            background-image:none;
            border: 2px solid #747e96;
            border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
            border-radius: 10em 0 5em 2em;
        }
        .inactiveTab {
            background-color: #EDE3D1;
            color: #838483;
            background-image: none
            border-radius: 10em 0 5em 2em;
        }

        .exceptionText{
                                 font-style:italic;
                                 font-size:16px;
                                 font-weight:bold;
                                 text-align:center;
<apex:form id="frm">
        <apex:tabpanel id="tbp" switchType="client" selectedTab="name1" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab" headerAlignment="center">
 <apex:tab label="Noise Dictionary" onclick="myFunction(); ">
                <apex:pageBlock title="Noise Words Dictionary" id="pb" >
</apex:pageBlock>

            </apex:tab>
<apex:tab id="tabId" label="Contact Dictionary" > 

              <apex:pageBlock title="Contact Dictionary" id="PageB" >
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:tab>
 <apex:tab id="tabIds" label="Account Dictionary" >
             <apex:pageBlock title="Account Dictionary" id="PageB1" >
</apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:tab>

        </apex:tabpanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go throught the use of Render and ReRender.for help you can follow the following link --
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AUDnIAO

Comment: Please add relevant detail from the linked resource or your answer will likely be deleted. Link-only answers can break over time and are considered fragile.

Comment: @AdrianLarson sure , thanks for the warning.I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

With help of   tag and **onclick** function on **tabPanel**. You can render the entire tabPanel when you click on tabs.

You have to add **DummyFunc()** method in controller, In **actionFunction** we have to pass method name for **action attribute**  that's reason i have created dummyFunc().

```
 public void DummyFunc() {       
    }
```

Change below code in **visual force** page

```
<apex:form id="frm">
        <apex:actionFunction name="actionFunc" action="{! DummyFunc}" reRender="tbp"/>
        <apex:tabpanel id="tbp" onclick="actionFunc();" switchType="client" selectedTab="name1" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab" headerAlignment="center">

            <apex:tab label="Noise Dictionary">
                <apex:pageBlock title="Noise Words Dictionary" id="pb" >
            </apex:pageBlock>                
            </apex:tab>

            <apex:tab id="tabId" label="Contact Dictionary" >                 
                <apex:pageBlock title="Contact Dictionary" id="PageB" >
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:tab>

            <apex:tab id="tabIds" label="Account Dictionary" >
                <apex:pageBlock title="Account Dictionary" id="PageB1" >
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:tab>

        </apex:tabpanel>
    </apex:form>
```

In the above **actionFucntion** i have passed **tabPanel** id for render. You can pass **pageBlock** id also for render you tabs eg..  **reRender="PageB"**

Check below working code i have tried for render you **Tab**

Controller  : **ApexTabExCntr**

```
public class ApexTabExCntr {
    Public integer num1 {get { return ++num1; } set;}
    Public integer num2 {get { return ++num2; } set;}
    public ApexTabExCntr() {
        num1=1;
        num2=2;        
    }
    public void DummyFunc() {       
    } 
}
```

VisualForce Page : **ApexTabEx**

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" controller="ApexTabExCntr">  
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="actionFunc" action="{! DummyFunc}" reRender="AccountTabPanel"/>
        <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" id="AccountTabPanel"  onclick="actionFunc();" >        
            <apex:tab label="One" name="name1" id="tabOne" reRender="PageA" >
                <apex:pageBlock title="Contact tabOne" id="PageA" >
                    content for tab {! num1}
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:tab>
            <apex:tab label="Two" name="name2" id="tabTwo" reRender="PageB" >
                <apex:pageBlock title="Contact tabTwo" id="PageB" >
                    content for tab {! num2}
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:tab>
        </apex:tabPanel>        
    </apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```